# Sort data and insertion that orders automatically - Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, symfony

Well, I know I might get some downvotes for this question, but I really need help or I won't have any hair left in a few hours.

I got an array like this:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  object((2) {
    ["nivId"]=>int(3)
    ["nivOrdre"]=>int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  object((2) {
    ["nivId"]=>int(4)
    ["nivOrdre"]=>int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  object((2) {
    ["nivId"]=>int(6)
    ["nivOrdre"]=>int(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  object((2) {
    ["nivId"]=>int(2)
    ["nivOrdre"]=>int(4)
  }
  [4]=>
  object((2) {
    ["nivId"]=>int(1)
    ["nivOrdre"]=>int(5)
  }
  [5]=>
  object((2) {
    ["nivId"]=>int(5)
    ["nivOrdre"]=>int(6)
  }
}
```

In my HTML I display them ordered by `nivOrdre`

I can modify `nivOrdre` for each of them in the HTML and it changes in the db.

What I want to do is when I modify a `nivOrdre`, all the others that are higher get incremented by one.

I can't get the loops to work properly because of the `nivId` and `nivOrdre`, can't figure how to write that algorithm.

I also tried to **not** increment when there is a gap between two values.
My code has a lots of bugs and I am desperate to make it work someday...

Here is what I did :

```
public function modNiveaux($niveau) {
    $niveaux = $this->getNiveauxRepository()->findBy(array(), array('nivOrdre' => 'ASC'));
    $add = false; $ite=0;
    for($i=$niveau->getNivOrdre(); $i<sizeof($niveaux); $i++) {
        echo $niveau->getNivOrdre().':'.$niveaux[$i]->getNivOrdre().'<br/>';
        if($niveau->getNivOrdre() != $niveaux[$i-1]->getNivOrdre() && $niveau->getNivOrdre() != $niveaux[$i-1]->getNivOrdre())
            $add=true;
    }

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($niveaux); $i++){
        if($niveaux[$i]->getNivOrdre() == $niveau->getNivOrdre()){
            $ite=$i;
        }
    }

    if($add){
        for($i=$ite; $i<=sizeof($niveaux)-1; $i++){
            $niveaux[$i]->setNivOrdre($niveaux[$i]->getNivOrdre()+1);
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($niveaux[$i]);
        }
    }

    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

That code is in the `Service` and called in the `Controller` like that :

```
public function updateAction($id) {
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $postData = $request->get('niveaux');
        $id = $postData['id'];
    }

    $this->niveauxService = $this->get("intranet.niveaux_service");
    $niveau = $this->niveauxService->getNiveau($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new NiveauxType(), $niveau);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->niveauxService->saveNiveau($niveau);
        $this->niveauxService->modNiveaux($niveau);
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Objet sauvegardé avec succès');
    } else {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('noticeError', 'L\'objet n\'a pu être mis à jour.');
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'id' => $id,
    );
}
```

If someone has an idea to make it work I will be eternally thankful..

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For example, if I change the `nivOrdre`:2 and set it to 3, the 4 become 5, 5 become 6 etc... The 1 stays the same

Comment: So by "if I **modify** `nivOrdre` in HTML" do you mean "if I **increment** `nivOrdre`" ? Or can you change for example `nivOrdre` from `2` to `4`?

Comment: Yes I can add the value I want, that's why it became more complicated

Comment: So which values should change in case of changing `2` to `4`? Greater than `2` or grater than `4`?

Comment: Greater than **4** and then the previous **2** (becamed **4**) is now displayed after **3**. Because each one has a string value displayed next to the ordre but it's not useful in my problem

Comment: Last question. :) So after this operation there should be `nivOrdre` values : `1,3,4,5,6,7`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and the label between **3** and **4** changes. The label follows the `nivId` to be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on your question and comments all you want to do is to increment all niveaux with ordre greater or equal than the new value of changed entity.

Since the entity provided to `modNiveaux` method already has assigned new value, inside the service you need to retrieve entities with greater all equal `ordre` than the current (except the current!) and increment them.

The value of *current* entity is already changed by the form, so there's nothing to do with it.

That would be something like this:

```
public function modNiveaux($niveau) {
    $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
    //greater or equal nivOrdre
    $criteria->where($criteria->expr()->gte('nivOrdre', $niveau->getNivOrdre()));
    //but not the current one
    $criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->neq('nivId', $niveau->getNivId()));

    $niveaux = $this->getNiveauxRepository()->matching($criteria);
    //increment all of them and persist
    foreach($niveaux as $item) {
        $item->setNivOrdre($item->getNivOrdre()+1);
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($item);
    }

    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

This code is of course not tested and may contain simple mistakes, but this is the idea.

Comment: Well, it works like a charm for what I tested ! Just need to implement the fact that it doesn't increment everything when the next value is not directly the previous+1. Anyway thank you a lot !